# How do I number the equation as a text?

Tags: equations, labels

```
\begin{align}
  \mathcal{L}_{\lambda} =  u_{1}(h) - u_{1}(h^{*}) + T \geq 0 \text{(foc$\lambda$)}, \label{eqn:foca1}\\
  \mathcal{L}_{T} = -1 + \lambda = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lambda = 1 \text{(focT)} ,\label{eqn:focb1}\\
  \mathcal{L}_{h} =- u'_{2}(h) + \lambda u'_{1}(h) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lambda = \frac{u'_{2}(h)}{u'_{1}(h)} \text{(foch)}.\label{eqn:focc1}\\
  \lambda \geq 0 \text{(nn)}, \label{eqn:focd1}\\
  \lambda \mathcal{L}_{\lambda} =  \lambda [u_{1}(h) - u_{1}(h^{*}) + T] = 0 \text{(cs$\lambda$)} .\label{eqn:foce1}
\end{align}
```

I want to have foc$\lambda$, \text{(focT)}, etc, as an equation number on the other sides if that makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\tag` command -- it supplies the `()` brackets for you:

[image]

Here's the full MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \mathcal{L}_{\lambda} =  u_{1}(h) - u_{1}(h^{*}) + T \geq 0,
      \tag{\text{foc$\lambda$}} \label{eqn:foca1}\\
  \mathcal{L}_{T} = -1 + \lambda = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lambda = 1,
      \tag{\text{focT}}\label{eqn:focb1}\\
  \mathcal{L}_{h} =- u'_{2}(h) + \lambda u'_{1}(h) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lambda = \frac{u'_{2}(h)}{u'_{1}(h)},
      \tag{\text{foch}}\label{eqn:focc1}\\
  \lambda \geq 0,  \tag{\text{nn}}\label{eqn:focd1}\\
  \lambda \mathcal{L}_{\lambda} =  \lambda [u_{1}(h) - u_{1}(h^{*}) + T] = 0.
      \tag{\text{cs$\lambda$}}\label{eqn:foce1}
\end{align}

By \eqref{eqn:foca1}.

\end{document}
```